# Angular 1x and Node.js in same project in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

In WebStorm, can I run Angular and Node in the same project? Is there a project template for this?

I also notice node modules are not checked in with code by WebStorm into repository (TFS) in my tests. Is this normal? Trying to figure out best practices.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you. This is the project in which i have used 'AngularJS' as frontend and node server as backend. [github project](https://github.com/pradeepb6/tk_praktikum)

Answer (score 0):

bunch of seeds you can find by googling "Mean Seed". I personally prefer Yeoman - https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack, but you can choose what fit your need better. Just make sure it's updated and popular, some use quite exotic libraries.